# How to automate program startup?

Tags: windows, automation

How can I go about launching an application to process a .txt file whenever the file is dropped into a specified folder in a windows environment?

Comment: Are you looking for a program that will do this for you? Or looking into how to write a program to do something like this? If looking to write a program, what language are you planning on using?

Comment: I plan on using visual c++ unless the job can be accomplished using a script.

Comment: I will be using C# instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention which programming language you are using, but in C# or VB.NET you can set up a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) object.

Failing that, you can write a [shell extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the class.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no current language, Try http://www.autoitscript.com/site/ works well and not really that hard to do what you want.

Comment: Does this support launching an application in response to a drag and drop action?

Comment: You can use something like this AutoIt UDF http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/113560-filesystemmonitor-udf/ and then create a condition to launch the app when that folder changes.

Comment: This one here might even be better. http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/113560-filesystemmonitor-udf/?p=800664 This one is just for the folders, so it will monitor for new files added and then you can do a shellexecute() to launch your app.